# Is it possible to connect a local Python app to Azure OIDC?

Tags: python, excel, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

My setup is as follows:
I make API calls from python scripts activated in excel, using the wonderful [xlwings](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings).
This enables complex data extraction and transformation workflows to be coded in nice python instead of annoying VBA. It also makes these workflows available to non-coding users at the click of an embedded button.

My problem:
My API calls used hardcoded API keys in the past. This is a big security no-no. Now my API calls need to go through OIDC (OAuth2) authentication in Azure AD.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to trigger OIDC authentication (in Azure AD) from a local Python script?
2. Where could I securely store my client secret in such a setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this.  You don't say which APIs you are calling but any of them act the same.

There are two types of authentication: interactive and non-interactive.  You'll need to describe the one you want, but since you're concerned about hard-coded keys, let's assume that you want interactive.

This means that when a user wants to access the data, the user is prompted for credentials in a browser.  An access token is returned to the application which is then used to call the APIs.  No hardcoded keys are used and the token expires after a period of time.

You can get started by referring to this documenation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate